# Export to CSV with newline character in data

Tags: c#

The  data contains new line character ,so every time it appends the new line to the data exported and records get increased also the data contains "," separated values values 
what i have implemented is this solution

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName + ',');
        }

        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //string[] fields = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
            //                    ToArray();
            //sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));

            //for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
            //{
                var fields = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString().WrapInQuotesIfContains(","));
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                //add separator
                //sb.Append(dt.Rows[i][k].ToString() + ';');
            //}
            //append new line
            //sb.Append("\r\n");`enter code here`
        }
```

Comment: Handy tips for you for future questions: 1. Actually ask a question, rather than leaving people to infer what you are asking for and (2) put a bit of effort into it: show what you have done so far for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Wrap and fields with newlines or `,` characters in quotes (and don't forget to convert `"` into `""` characters.
2. Pick one of the many excellent third party CSV packages available for .NET and let it deal with it.